# Git could not lock config file <path>: Permission denied... Windows 10

Tags: git, git-config

I get the following error when Git GUI create new repository

```
error: could not lock config file C:/Program Files/Git/etc/.gitconfig: Permission denied <...>  
Permission denied  
    while executing  
"close $fd"  
    (procedure "git" line 5)  
    invoked from within  
"git config --global --add gui.recentrepo $path"  
    (procedure "_append_recentrepos" line 14)  
    invoked from within  
"_append_recentrepos [pwd]"  
    (procedure "_git_init" line 17)  
    invoked from within  
"_git_init $this"  
    (procedure "choose_repository::_do_new2" line 5)  
    invoked from within  
"choose_repository::_do_new2 ::choose_repository::__o1::__d"  
    invoked from within  
".buttons.next invoke "  
    invoked from within  
".buttons.next instate !disabled { .buttons.next invoke } "  
    invoked from within  
".buttons.next instate pressed { .buttons.next state !pressed; .buttons.next instate !disabled {  >.buttons.next invoke } } "
    (command bound to event)
```

each time I try to create a new repository.

I partially solved using this:
https://dirask.com/posts/Git-git-config-error-could-not-lock-config-file-Permission-denied-Kj825D

Is there any way to fix the problem once for all? On Windows, I use file explorer to go to the folder, right click and select "GIT GUI here" from popup menu, and create the new repository, and I get the error.
If I select "git bash here" from popup menu and type git init, this works!

What can I do?

here follows permission settings
settings applies to the following users/group/entity

- ALL PACKET APPS
- system
- administrator
- users

each ones has enabled:

- full control
- modify
- read and execute
- read
- write

These applies to

- Main applications, under C:\Program Files\Git\bin (bash.exe, git.exe, sh.exe)
- C:\Program Files\Git\etc.gitconfig

Thank you,
Roberto

Comment: why the svn tag ?

Comment: What happens if you use Windows Explorer to navigate to the folder, then create a new folder and select that one with "git gui here", then create a new repo?

Comment: @code-apprentice: is exactly what I do to get the error. If I open "Git Bash Here" instead I can init the repository. Thank you